# SQL to get combine rows in single row based on a column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table as follow:

```
+---+---+---+
|obj|col|Val|
+---+---+---+
|1  |c1 | v1|
+---+---+---+
|1  |c2 | v2|
+---+---+---+
|2  |c1 | v3|
+---+---+---+
|2  |c2 | v4|
+---+---+---+
```

And I am looking for SQL that will give the result in the following format

```
+---+---+---+
|obj|c1 |c2 |
+---+---+---+
|1  |v1 | v2|
+---+---+---+
|2  |v3 | v4|
+---+---+---+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this SQL, I am checking for col = 'c?' and printing out the corresponding Val. But the reason for group by is to avoid all NULL values in case the condition doesn't match. By grouping on obj all the NULL values will be avoided and produce the desired result.

```
SELECT obj,
       MAX( CASE WHEN col = 'c1' THEN Val END ) AS c1,
       MAX( CASE WHEN col = 'c2' THEN Val END ) AS c2
  FROM Table
 GROUP BY obj;
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to select all the unique id from your table

```
select distinct id
from a_table_you_did_not_name
```

how you can use that to left join to your columns

```
select base.id, one.val as c1, two.val as c2
from (
  select distinct id
  from a_table_you_did_not_name
) base
left join a_table_you_did_not_name one on one.id = base.id and one.col = 'c1'
left join a_table_you_did_not_name two on two.id = base.id and two.col = 'c2'
```

> note: your case is a relatively simple case of this kind of join -- I coded it like this because using my method can be extended to the more complicated cases and still work.  There are some other ways for this particular requirement that might be simpler.
>
> *specifically the most common one is joining to multiple tables, not all in the same table.  My method will still work in those cases.*

Comment: This is most definitely *not* the way to pivot data in SQL, and in Oracle. The other Answer (marked Correct) shows the most general solution. In Oracle 11 and above, there is also the `PIVOT` clause. No joins are needed for pivoting.

Comment: @mathguy - there is no internal difference between doing it this way and using the PIVOT clause.  And the other answer is not the most general solution consider the case where you have two tables and you want a result with 5 columns.  Mine extends to that case and Teja's does not.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "internal difference", I am not familiar with that concept. But the difference is that your solution reads the base table three times, instead of just once with the standard PIVOT solution. (Are you denying that?) So you do a lot of unnecessary and expensive I/O. And the other solution IS the most general solution for **pivoting**. Your solution is not "pivoting"; it is more general, in the sense you stated it, but that solves a problem the OP didn't have in this thread.

Comment: Yes I am denying that -- I believe this query a pivot will work exactly the same if you have two tables (which is the much more common case) as I said in the yellow comment "There are some other ways for this particular requirement that might be simpler."   Remember also that a GROUP BY has horrible performance compared to an indexed join in many cases (eg large and sparse).  Group by requires a lot of memory and processing.

Comment: You are missing my point. PIVOT reads the table only once, your joins read the table three times. You say you are denying that (and if you are, just check execution plans to see for yourself), but then you give a reason that has nothing to do with this.

Comment: @mathguy -- I got your point.  The thing is PIVOT is not a magic word -- it still has to implemented and it is implemented in doing joins as I describe.  It is syntactic sugar for what I'm showing.  It looks nice but does not  change the laws of mathematics just because it is used.  In this case -- where all the columns are in the same table -- you can use a GROUP BY and in some cases (depending on system memory, table size, etc etc) it will be faster, but not always.  I like you point, your point is good.  But the word PIVOT does not change how math works.

Comment: PIVOT is not a magic word. It is a technical word (with a very clear definition - taking data from rows and presenting it in columns instead). Not my definition; if you don't use that definition, you should say so, but in the context of databases I don't think we are free to use words any way we want. And, in Oracle 11.1 and above, PIVOT is also the name of a specific clause - but that is not the sense in which I was using the word. And, just to be specific, "pivot" as a general concept applies to a SINGLE table (or row set from whatever previous processing) at a time.